# Center text in a single table cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Suppose I have simple table. While I want the columns in general to be flush both right and left, there are certain cells that I want to be centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\def\x{This is a paragraph of text that should be flush both right and left. Centering an adjacent cell should not cause this cell to be centered.}
\def\y{Centered text}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}|p{2in}}
\x & \y \\
\y & \x \\
\x & \x
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This has the output that I expected.

[image]

But what do I do when I want to center the cells that say "Centered text"? I tried to do it with the `\centering` command,

```
\def\y{\centering Centered text}
```

but it comes up with the following error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
```

How can I center individual cells?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The error occurs because `\\` is redefined by `\centering` (and other commands, such as `\raggedright`), but the problem only occurs for the final column. To fix it you can load the `array` package and add `\arraybackslash` after `\centering` in the  cell, which restores the definition of `\\`.

Another option, mentioned by Gonzalo Medina in a comment, is to use `\tabularnewline` instead of `\\` to end the row, which does not require `array`:

```
\x & \centering\y \tabularnewline
```

(The `\arraybackslash` command is simply defined as `\def\arraybackslash{\let\\\tabularnewline}`)

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{array}

\def\x{This is a paragraph of text that should be flush both right and left. Centering an adjacent cell should not cause this cell to be centered.}
\def\y{Centered text}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{2in}|p{2in}}
\x & \centering\arraybackslash\y \\
% \x & \centering\y \tabularnewline  % alternative version of the previous line
\centering\y & \x \\
\x & \x
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Add a multicolumn that spans a single column.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}

\def\x{This is a text aligned according to column alignment defined in tablular.}
\def\y{Centered text}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
   \x & \x \\
   \x & \x \\
   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\y} & \x 
\end{tabular}
 
\endtabular}

\end{document}
```